# How can I place an .exe file on all of my domain machines?

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2008, group-policy

I'm trying to place a specific .exe file on all of my domain machines, I'm not sure if this is possible but I'm trying to do using Group Policy Object. here are the screenshots of what I've done so far.. it doesn't seem to be working, what's the issue?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfFyt.png)

[GPO Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfFyt.png)

[GPO Settings 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eW1vc.png)

Comment: You'd better publishing an MSI package, https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/group-policy/use-group-policy-to-install-software